# 5.9 experience index score for a last generation Samsung SSD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-experience-index

I got a Samsung 840 Pro and I reinstalled windows. 
Before this, I had a score of 4.5 with my old HDD drive.
For Samsung I got a shameful 5.9 (since this device has the lowest score, the whole laptop is graded as 5.9).
Why?
On Windows 8 which I had installed for a day, the rating was 7.7 (for SSD).

My system is Toshiba Qosmio x505 with Intel P55 chipset. Win 7 32 bit.
I have the SATA AHCI driver installed.

Comment: More informs is required to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound - What kind of info. I will provide it.

Comment: @Altar Is the 5.9 the rating for (just) the drive section of WEI, or the total score or WEI?

Comment: The overall Windows Experience Index is taken as the lowest of the subsystem scores, which should be listed on the Windows Experience Index control panel.

Comment: WEI is shameful to begin with. Use PASSMARK or something else if you want a real benchmark of your system.

Comment: If Windows 8 gave a better rating than Windows 7 for the same device, perhaps it's a driver issue, such that Win8 has newer drivers and thus gets better performance; you may want to see whether Samsung offers Windows 7 drivers for the device, and install them if so.

Comment: @kobaltz there is nothing wrong with WEI as long as you use it for what it was intended. It is not meant to be a benchmark, it is only meant to be an indicator as to how well the system should perform. It does that very well.

Comment: post the most recent Disk.Assessment XML from **C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore**

Comment: @AaronMiller: Seems it *was* a driver issue. You should have posted that as an answer. :)

Comment: @Karan Posted as an answer anyway. Who knows? Altar could still accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing a newer Intel chipset driver. The driver provided by Toshiba was horrible.

Answer (score 2):

If Windows 8 gave a better rating than Windows 7 for the same device, perhaps it's a driver issue, such that Win8 has newer drivers and thus gets better performance; you may want to see whether Samsung offers Windows 7 drivers for the device, and install them if so.